# css disable button not working in tablets

Tags: javascript, css, button, mobile, disable

-I have a button: 
 
-I want to disable it with javascript:
document.getElementById("input-datestart").disabled = true;
-Css:

```
input:disabled {
    background-color: #fff!important;
    color: #000;
}
```

text color [color: #000;] 
On my computer's browser it's working, but on tablet, it's not working,
please find below the image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJM52.png)

Comment: Hello,,Can you please share HTML code? or upload code in jsfiddle and share the link

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/giangphan1102/2mruf3cv/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this for multiple OS's.

> Make the background and text visible to screen what I observe in your fiddle is it `transparent` for the users, so feel free to modify a color code to make it consistent across `devices` and `platforms`.

```js
document.getElementById("input-datestart").disabled = true;
```

```css
  input:disabled {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #880000;
  /* Override iOS / Android font color change */
  -webkit-opacity: 1;
  /* Override iOS opacity change affecting text & background color */
  color: #880000;
  /* Override IE font color change */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>

  <input value="text value" name="datePlan" id="input-datestart" readonly="" type="text">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Glad I was able to assist you! kindly vote if it is worth voting! thanks

Answer (score -1):

Please try using webkit prefix along with CSS properties, I hope it's for Android platform